# Dynamic execution of the methods of bean object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Currently i have one requirment our backend spring rest api will receive the data in encrypted json format (few fields are encrypted and few fields are plain text)
and then applies the decryption  ,then applies some business logic on the data ,finally stores data into database.

This decryption logic is repeatining muliple service implementations methods . 
So we desided to isolate the decryption logic from actual business logic.

i am using spring aop to decrypting the data and after decrypting same 
object i am passing to service layer methods.

But my service layer methods contains the different types of objects as arguments

Ex :

```
    processEmployee(EmployeeRequest request)

    procesStudent(StudentRequest request)
```

I was looking for a way how can i dynamically change 
the data on the same object fields it self ( Ex: EmployeeRequest,StudentRequest )

The following approach i have tried and stuck with 4th step.

1.Introduced a new annotation.

2.Annotate those fields which are having the encrypted data.

3.Retrieve all the annotated fields.

4.Each field data we will apply the decryption logic and 
 decrypted data will be injected on the same field again

i was looking for the api to achieve 4th step ?

Is there any api available to dynamically execute 
the methods on the same object 
or any reference please point me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to not use the same POJO for both encrypted / decrypted class. It make confusing for future usage (as if I received an EmployeeRequest instance, is it decrypted or not?), and also limit the type (as your encrypted/decrypted data must be the same type).

Now, for the implementation, you have two choices:

1. Using explicit `ConversionService`

Register a converter:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeRequestConverter implements Converter<EmployeeRequest, EmployeeRequest> {

     @Override
     public EmployeeRequest convert(EmployeeRequest source) {
           // Apply your decryption logic
     }
}
```

Make the similar converters for other request objects.

Now in your controller:

```
public class MyController {

    private ConversionService conversionService;

    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(...)
    public void aRequest(@RequestBody EmployeeRequest request) {
        myService.execute(conversionService.convert(request, EmployeeRequest.class));
    }

}
```

2. Using reflection.

Precondition: You have `@Encrypted` annotation on encrypted fields.

Unlike the first solution, you do not create explicit converter for each type of request.

```
@Service
public class DecryptionService {

     public void <T> T decrypt(T input) {
          Field[] fields = input.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
          for (Field field : fields) {
               Encrypted encrypted = field.getAnnotation(Encrypted.class);
               if (encrypted != null) {
                   try{
                      field.setAccessible(true);
                      Object val = field.get(input);
                      // Base on @Encrypted annotation in your val, do the decryption
                      Object decryptedVal = ...;
                      field.set(input, decryptedVal);
                   } catch (Exception ex) {
                   }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Now you can apply this service for your controllers.

You might want to cache the `Class.getDeclaredFields()` and the mapping between `Class<?> -> @Encrypted fields` for performance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions , In the second option how can i decrypt the data for the type List<String> type ?     For example if my List contains the 3 elements how can i  decrypt the three elements , do i need to go with type checking ?

Comment: The decryption logic is up to your service. One typical way is like public key encryption, where you use a publickey to encrypt your data and use your private key to decyprt it

Comment: Sorry my statement miss guiding you .if my object contains the field type List<String> when I called field.get() will return list type I have to decrypt each element in the list and will add back again in the list  so how can achieve this do we have any API method for specific types?

Comment: You can create your own API. Check if the field type is a List then cast it and apply your decryption logic. Again, the decryption/encryption logic are your requirement.